# Keeping an active sum value for huge tables

Tags: database, database-design

Imagine I have a table that consists of millions of rows of data.And this table handles the stock in-outs of a warehouse,if a stock goes in,some app adds a row,with positive quantity,if a stock goes out,it adds a row with negative quantity.And as a result,we get the total number of stocks in the warehouse by summing all quantity values (based on stock type,warehouse id etc).What is the best practise to keep the actual amount in the warehouse?

1-Summing all the data when needed? (Considering this is a huge table,it's slow)

2-Keeping a second table,updating it with actual amount as the app adds or removes the rows?

3-Any other way?

Ok more info,it will be used in an MRP system,data updates would be quite frequent,the table may consist of 20 or more columns with several column types.And the total amount could be requested at anytime.

Comment: Millions of rows is not a huge table and just because a table is huge doesn't mean that it's going to be slow. You haven't provided any context: how often will you be using this sum? Is it used in a website? Batch environment? How often is it used? How often does it change?

Comment: I agree with Ben. But I'll add that if you do decide to denormalize by keeping the sums on an aggregated table, then you really don't want the app to be updating that table... you should use triggers.

Comment: Well this is still a concept,so I can not give you any specific data about the tables or schemas,but isn't there a best practise for this kind of usages?

Comment: When it comes to databases there is rarely a catch-all "best practice". It depends on the RDBMS and the environment. You haven't mentioned how often the data will change yet for instance. Then it depends on the size of your hardware and the necessity for the value to be accurate. For instance, if you have 100 people updating the value constantly and it doesn't need to be 100% accurate (i.e. the business logic is enforced elsewhere properly in the DB) this might be something you want to do every minute to stop attempting to do it 100 times a minute and failing...

Comment: Do you need to sum per whole table or per SKU? How many rows per SKU are expected?